# Hypothesis testing for Gamma distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

I have a sample $X_1,...,X_n \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\alpha, \beta$ - unknown parameters of Gamma distribution. How to build a test for testing $H_0:\alpha=1$ against $H_1:\alpha>1$?

Comment: There are several papers available: [Keating et al. (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1269846?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), [Bhaumik et al. (2015)](http://www.healthstats.org/articles/Bhaumik_Kapur%20et%20al%202015.pdf).

Comment: Also, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233032930_Testing_Parameters_of_a_Gamma_Distribution_for_Small_Samples. Note however, that $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ is the notation for the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Upper_incomplete_Gamma_function) and even though Wikipedia uses this notation for the gamma distribution, one is better off using something else like GD$(x;\alpha,\beta)$, to avoid ambiguity.